# Free boundary condition for American Option using Mathematica NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

Was wondering if there is a Mathematica example solving the free boundary condition for American Option using NDSolveValue (free boundary condition is continue to hold v.s. early exercise of the option)...

Comment: Do you mean to solve the Heston PDE with American call option like this one https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378475420301816 ? We have discussed one example on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239778/how-to-implement-fem-for-a-2d-pde-with-variable-coefficients/240035#240035