# Non linear PDE solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

Could someone advise if it is possible to solve the following PDE with Mathematica? I am quite a beginner in Mathematica so any input would be highly appreciated.

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\frac{\partial^2  u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}+a\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial y}}{3\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial y}}\right)^2-r  u(x,y)=0.$,
where $\sigma$, a and r are come constants.

The domain for $\sigma=0.85$, $r=0.05$ and $a=50$ is specified as follows
$y \leq 0.52 + 0.46 x; x \leq 0.52 + 0.46 y;  x\geq 0;  y \geq 0; x \leq 0.97;  y \leq 0.97$

witht the boundary conditions are

1. $u(x,y)=0$ for $x=0,y\leq0.46$;
2. $u(x,y)=249.5  \mathrm{e}^{-34.5784 x} (-1 +  \mathrm{e}^{34.6 x})$ for $y=0, x\leq0.46$;
3. $\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial x}=1$ for $0.46\leq x\leq 0.97$, on $x = 0.52 + 0.46 y $;
4. $\frac{\partial  u(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$ for $0.46\leq y\leq 0.97$, on $y = 0.52 + 0.46 x $.

Comment: We can solve this problem, but due to forum rules you need first show your efforts. I can recommend this post with similar problem https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239778/how-to-implement-fem-for-a-2d-pde-with-variable-coefficients?rq=1